# Is there a way to accept null in resultset

Tags: sql-server, kotlin

I am trying to view data from the SQL Server and I have a column (note) that accept null value because it is not necessary for the user to input any values. I tried using the "rs.wasNull" method as below:

```
var Note : String = rs.getString("note")
                if(rs.wasNull()){
                    Note = ""
                }
```

But I have still facing the error saying that the "rs.getString("note) cannot be null. Is there any possible ways to return null value?

Below are my whole code:

```
private fun displayData() {
    val sqlCon = SQLCon()
    connection = sqlCon.connectionClass()!!
    var cUser : String? = intent.getStringExtra("Current User")
        if (connection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to make connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
           
            try {
                val sql : String=
                    "SELECT * FROM Goals where Username =  '$cUser' "
                statement = connection!!.createStatement()
                var rs : ResultSet = statement!!.executeQuery(sql)
               

                while (rs.next())
                {

 var Note : String = rs.getString("note")
                if(rs.wasNull()){
                    Note = ""
                }
                    gList.add(GoalList(rs.getString("gName"), rs.getDouble("tAmount"), rs.getDouble("sAmount"), rs.getString("note"), rs.getString("date")))
                  
                }
                rs.close()
                statement!!.close()

                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } catch (e: Exception) { Log.e("Error", e.message!!) }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use non-nullable return type for note variable:

```
var Note : String = rs.getString("note")
```

First, the variable name should start with a lowercase letter -> note.
Secondly, return value must be nullable

```
var note : String? = rs.getString("note")
```

In accordance with JavaDoc getString function:

> Returns: the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value
> returned is null

So no need to check if it was null or not, you can use the following construction to pass default value:

```
var note : String = rs.getString("note") ?: ""
```

Comment: I was able to solve it by using the solution you provided. Thanks a lot !!